# How do you simply obtain an array of pixel data from an image by java?

Tags: java, arrays, pixel, acm-java-libraries

I need to work code to analyze the image to pixels in the form of an array.
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Paint the `Image` to a `BufferedImage`:

```
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D graphics = bi.createGraphics();
graphics.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, null);
graphics.dispose();
```

Now you can use method of the `BufferedImage` class to manipulate the image.

Maybe using the `getRGB(...)` or `getSubImage(...)` methods?